# Solids of revolution, how come we use the inverse function when we use method of cylindrical shells?

Tags: calculus, geometry

Doing my second course in college calculus, and we are doing integrals and volumes by slicing/solids of revolution. The question I had trouble with was:

"Find the volume of a solid $S$, using the method of cylindrical shells, that is generated by rotating about the $x$-axis the region bounded by $y = x^2$, $y = 0$, and $x = 1$. "

I was having a real hard time figuring out why I kept getting the wrong answer when using the formula for the method of cylindrical shells, $V = 2\pi \int xf(x)\, \mathrm{d}x$
for determining a volume, until I saw that you are supposed to use the inverse function in the formula. Simply put, how come? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: That formula is for when you rotate around the $y$ axis, to apply it you need to first flip over the diagonal $y =x$ which corresponds to taking the inverse function.

Comment: Great tip, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw the picture.  You're rotating about the $x$-axis.  The radius of the shell is $y$.  The shell extends from the the graph rightward to the line $x=1$.  The horizontal distance from graph rightward to the line $x=1$ is the length of the segment from $(x,y)$ to $(1,y)$, where $y=f(x)$.  That means it goes from $(f^{-1}(y),y)$ to $(1,y)$.  So the surface area of the shell is
$$
\text{circumference}\times\text{(horizontal) height} = 2\pi y(1-x) = 2\pi y (1-f^{-1}(y)).
$$
The infinitely small thickness of the shell is $dy$, so you integrate
$$
\int_{y=0}^{y=1} 2\pi y (1-f^{-1}(y))\,dy.
$$
You could say the aformentioned segment goes from $(x,y)$ to $(1,y)$, i.e. from $(x,f(x))$ to $(1,f(x))$ and you have
$$
\int_{x=0}^{x=1} 2\pi f(x)\, (1-x)\  \  \underbrace{\Big(f'(x)\,dx\Big)}_{\text{This is }dy.}
$$
and that's the same thing.

At any rate, if $y=f(x)$ then $x=f^{-1}(y)$.

(All this works if $f$ is monotone, but not necessarily otherwise.)

Comment: @AndréNicolas : You're right: I neglected the fact that it was to be _under_ the curve.

Comment: OK, I've edited it.

Comment: Aha, I get it now! Great to see that it could be done "either way", both in terms of x & y. Very nice explanation, I'm saving this!

Answer (score 0):

It is the way the shells look that matters. In the usual case, i.e. rotating about the $y$-axis, the formula states:

$$
V = \int\limits_a^b \underbrace{(2 \pi x)}_{\text{circumference}} \underbrace{[f(x)]}_{\text{height}} \, \operatorname{d}x
$$

If you draw your specific problem, you will notice that your cylindrical shells end up with a radius of $y$ (circumference of $2 \pi y$) and a height of $1 - \sqrt{y}$.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks a lot!